# apache pig count not working, DUMP fails

Tags: apache-pig

I have assignment from class to find the number of entries filtered by a particular condition.

My problem as below my data set has following schema.

```
data1 = LOAD '/answers.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (qid:long,qt:long,tag:chararray,at:long);

qid = question ID, qt = question start time(in epoch time), at = answer end time(in epoch time);
```

Sample Data set:

sn   qid           qt                  tag                    at

1   563355  1235000081  php,error,gd,image-processing   1235000501

2   563355  1235000081  php,error,gd,image-processing   1235000551

3   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235000177

4   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235001545

5   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235002457

6   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235002809

7   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235003266

8   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235007817

9   563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235007913

10  563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235020626

11  563356  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1235040652

Need to find the number of question answered within 1hr.

Approach: PIG version 0.15.0

to find difference hrs between qt and at

```
A = FOREACH data1 GENERATE HoursBetween(ToDate(qt),ToDate(at)) AS diffhours;

B = FOREACH (FILTER A BY diffhours < 1) GENERATE diffhours;

C = GROUP B ALL;

D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(B.diffhours) ;
```

But when I dump D the job fails with below comment:

```
2016-04-06 01:13:17,736 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [112, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109, 109, 105, 110, 103] in field being converted to int, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "programming"> field discarded
2016-04-06 01:13:17,736 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 117, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 105, 118, 101, 34] in field being converted to int, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "subjective""> field discarded
```

in the end i get these...

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: <line 6, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'D'

Failed to parse: <line 6, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'D'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:244)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:182)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1707)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1680)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:623)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
================================================================================
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias D

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias D
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:935)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:927)
    ... 13 more
```

I am not able to understand the issue.

Comment: How does your data look like? Add some sample input data in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The embedded commas in the field **tag** is causing all the issues. Since you have defined only four fields in the schema, Pig is unable to read the data with your defined schema.

PigStorage is an extremely simple loader that does not handle special cases such as embedded delimiters or escaped control characters; it will split on every instance of the delimiter regardless of context.

Use Piggybank's CSVExcelStorage() which takes care of all the embedded commas within fields.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage; 
data1 = LOAD '/answers.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage();
```

Then execute the rest of your script. This wil give you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP` operator groups together tuples that have the same group key (key field).

Use of `COUNT` function is to compute the number of elements in a bag. `COUNT` requires a preceding `GROUP ALL` statement for global counts and a `GROUP BY` statement for group counts.

In your case you are calling count on B where the data is `filtered` and not `grouped by`

You need to call `COUNT` on the variable where the data is grouped.

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(B.diffhours);
```

Comment: So you mean to say it should be D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(C.diffhours);....?????